# python: How to convert numpy to vtkCellArray

Tags: python, vtk

If I have a numpy polys, how can I convert it to vtkCellArray?

For example, I can generate the polys using the following code:

```
def computePoly(rows, columns):
    numberOfPolys = (rows - 1) * (columns - 1)
    polys = np.empty((numberOfPolys, 4), np.int64)
    index = 0
    for row in range(rows - 1):
        for col in range(columns - 1):
            pts = [0] * 4
            pts[0] = col + row * columns
            pts[1] = pts[0] + 1
            pts[2] = pts[0] + columns + 1
            pts[3] = pts[0] + columns
            polys[index, :] = pts
    return polys
polys = computePoly(500, 500)
```

Then, how can I convert the `polys` into vtkCellArray?
I know that I can use vtkCellArray.InsertNextCell in the for-loop to generate the polys. The reason why I  generate the numpy polys is that I can use numba or some other methods to speed it up.

Thus, how can I convert a numpy polys (n*4) into vtkCellArray?

Answer (score 0):

I anser the question myself. The code should be:

```
def computePoly(rows, columns):
    numberOfPolys = (rows - 1) * (columns - 1)
    polys = np.empty((numberOfPolys*5), dtype=np.int64)
    for row in range(rows - 1):
        for col in range(columns - 1):
            index = (row*(columns-1)+col)*5
            polys[index] = 4
            polys[index+1] = col + row * columns
            polys[index+2] = col + row * columns + 1
            polys[index+3] = col + row * columns + columns + 1
            polys[index+4] = col + row * columns + columns
    return polys
npPolys = computePoly(rows, columns)
polys = vtk.vtkCellArray()
polys.SetCells(npPolys.shape[0], vtk.util.numpy_support.numpy_to_vtkIdTypeArray(npPolys, deep=True))
```